# Please make [gis] related tags reference gis.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-wiki

Would someone with the appropriate permissions please add a note to [gis](/questions/tagged/gis) something to the effect of: *"There is a Stack Exchange site devoted to Geographic Information Systems: https://gis.stackexchange.com/"*?

The same is true for the following tags:

- [geospatial](/questions/tagged/geospatial)
- [esri](/questions/tagged/esri)
- [spatial](/questions/tagged/spatial)
- [arcgis](/questions/tagged/arcgis)
- [arcobjects](/questions/tagged/arcobjects)
- [geolocation](/questions/tagged/geolocation)
- [geodjango](/questions/tagged/geodjango)
- [geocoding](/questions/tagged/geocoding)
- [openlayers](/questions/tagged/openlayers)
- [mapserver](/questions/tagged/mapserver)
- [postgis](/questions/tagged/postgis)
- [mapping](/questions/tagged/mapping)
- [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- [shapefile](/questions/tagged/shapefile)
- [gps](/questions/tagged/gps)

Comment: Shouldn't we wait until that site is out of beta?  Or is that creating a Catch-22?

Comment: @Bill We added links to Android in the android tag wiki, and they're also still in Beta. It helps as it may get better traffic for the site so that it can make the push out of Beta. If the site flops, then we can always rollback the addition.

Comment: @Grace: Precedent noted.  Just call me "Doc Daneeka."

Comment: @Bill, @Grace - there seems to be general agreement on the request now. How to move it to action? thanks.

Comment: @matt: I have to create the `gis` tag-wiki.  I pulled a quote from Wikipedia for a quick definition and I'm adding your link from the question above.  Are there any common references that should be included?

Comment: @bill, thanks! I would reword something like "Geographic information system (GIS): any system that captures, stores, analyzes, manages, and presents data linked to location. In the simplest terms, GIS is the merging of cartography, statistical analysis, and database technology. Also see [GIS.se](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) a dedicated Stack Exchange site for programmers, DBAs, Cartographers, Geographers and anyone interested in GIS professionally."