# Suggest more appropriate Stack Exchange sites for particular tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-exchange

After pointing the umpteenth LaTeX question poster from StackOverflow to tex.stackexchange.com, I thought it would be nice if people got a suggestion when entering a particular tag. In this case, it could trigger on the tags `tex` and `latex` which would catch most, if not all, of the questions that would be better asked on tex.stackexchange.com.

It could show a message above or below the "Related Questions" box, offering a link to transfer the current form's contents to the other Stack Exchange site.

Sorry if this has been suggested before; if so, I couldn't find it.

Comment: [Here is a *related* one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags) that suggests opening migration paths based on tags. But in thinking, plain suggestions for asking on other sites I think is mostly in comments. Do note that some users have taken to [adding advertisements for the new Stack Exchange sites in the tag wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74133/please-make-gis-related-tags-reference-gis-stackexchange-com) - this makes the link clear when hovering over any such tag.

Comment: I think if you ask a question and the only tag is [wordpress] it should automatically be migrated to wordpress.SE